# Automation of SQLCompare in Red Gate

Tags: build-automation, redgate

How can I automate the SqlCompare which compares and synchronizes the databases on different servers to run nightly?. Can you provide me a link or brief steps on how to handle this?

Comment: Can't you just check with Red Gate? As [this page here shows](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-compare/features), the feature *Command line automation for continuous integration* is only available in the **Pro** version - do you have that version??

Comment: Or you might be interested in the [Red-Gate SQL Comparison SDK](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-comparison-sdk/) to do this yourself in a tool?

Comment: There are Red Gate command line examples at http://downloads.red-gate.com/HelpPDF/ContinuousIntegrationForDatabasesUsingRedGateSQLTools.pdf (please contact us at Red Gate if you need assistance)

Comment: marc_s and David thanks for the links...yes my red gate is pro version

Comment: @marc_s can you give a brief steps of how to get to command line and process of automation?

Comment: @sunny: see the link that David Atkinson of Red-Gate published in his comment - I don't have anything more than that....

Answer (score 2):

you can run this from a .bat or .cmd file as a scheduled task

inside the task just do something as follows:

```
cd "C:\Program Files\Red Gate\SQL Compare 7"

SQLCompare /db1:<dbname>
           /db2:<dbname> 
           /synchronize
```

this will then perform the sync. Alternatively you could do this via CI system and call the same type of command via msbuild

Comment: is it enough just give ServerName: Database Name. where do i need to give the credentials?

Comment: There are some full examples using PowerShell and SQL Compare Command Line in this [blog post](https://www.simple-talk.com/blogs/2014/05/07/automating-deployments-with-the-sql-compare-command-line/).

Answer (score 2):

That may not be the right tool for the job SQLCompare is only concerned with schema, which can have some unfortunate effects on your data.  Consider if you change columns, RedGate will either

- work (when growing a size or something),
- drop the column (when changing a data type) or
- fail (what it should normally do).

It sounds like what you want is a nightly replication scheme, which will preserve the data as well as the schema.

Comment: Jeremy makes a good point. SQL Compare has this limitation. However, a new 'migrations' feature is coming soon which will allow custom scripts to be specified where required. Build automation and continuous integration will then be possible. Please sign up to the EA program to try out the beta when it comes out shortly.

Comment: I will be looking into that with great interest, although I'm skeptical how much schema changes can be automated and still preserve the data.

Comment: The idea behind migrations is that a custom script is associated with the object changes and committed to source control. This knowledge is reused by SQL Compare on subsequent deployments. The EA sign-up is here: http://www.red-gate.com/MessageBoard/viewtopic.php?t=12970 (this is for SQL Source Control, which is used in conjunction with SQL Compare)

Comment: This may help you get an idea of what is coming up: http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/markc/archive/2011/08/08/sql-source-control-and-custom-change-scripts.aspx

Answer (score 2):

I just solved this problem myself.  In my case, I have people that monkey around in the database unbeknownst to me and break the app.  Unfortunately I cannot get them to stop playing in the database so I wrote a simple program in C#.  It executes the SQL Compare command and looks in the response string for "The selected objects are identical".  If it doesn't find this, it emails me to notify me that something is up.  I used Windows Scheduler to schedule it for the morning and afternoon.

It's not the most elegant solution but it works.

Answer (score 1):

If you'd like to use a CI server to achieve this, you can now do this using the newly released CI command line and build script sample files available on http://www.red-gate.com/ci

For TeamCity users, there's a custom plugin.

These are free downloads, although bear in mind that you'll need the appropriate Red Gate license to use this beyond the trial period.

Comment: There are some examples in this [Jenkins and SQL CI blog post](http://thefutureofdeployment.com/set-database-continuous-integration-automated-deployment-jenkins-lunch/).

Answer (score 0):

You might try automation software to kick it off nightly using either the scheduler or a trigger. Automation Anywhere is good for this. Let me know if you want more info or just google it. -Tom